# Get table attribute or property value within ember controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

I have an ember application which has a table and a grid component within a page. I have enabled drag and drop feature which drags a value from a particular cell of a table and drops it into the empty space of the grid. As the tables have more than one column, I want to get the index position or I want to know which column's cell is being dragged. I want that index value of column within the controller.

Suppose a table has 3 rows with 3 columns. For all the elements within the first column being dragged, I want to get the index value as 1 similarly for 2nd and 3rd column.

Here is my .hbs code for the table

```
<table class = "table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6">Inbound Units</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {{#each currentbid as |currentbid|}}
               <tr>
                {{#each pull as |pull|}}
                      {{#if (eq pull.DRIVERNAME currentbid.DRIVERNAME)}}
                        <td abbr="P1">{{#draggable-object content=pull position=1 dragEndAction='dragEndAction'}}{{#draggable-object-target action="draganddrop"}}{{pull.P1}}{{/draggable-object-target}}{{/draggable-object}}</td>
                        <td>{{pull.P2}}</td>
                        <td>{{pull.P3}}</td>
                        <td>{{pull.P4}}</td>
                      {{/if}}
                      {{/each}}
                            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

As you can see wihtin the table td tag, I have specified abbr attribute. But I have no idea how to get the value of abbr within the controller. Any other way of getting this is also fine.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer applies to Ember 2.x.x and was written as of 2.15.

By default, actions assigned to a specific event via closure, like `ondragEnd={{action "someAction"}}` receive the event target as an argument:

```
actions: {
  someAction(event) {
    console.log(event.target)
  }
}
```

Possibly, you could use `event.target.parentElement.className` in your component to get the class name, then send the action and argument to your controller. Hopefully that selector will return the new parent and not the old one.

You can read about different ways to catch browser events in the [Ember Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/components/handling-events/).